# UIViewController come up blank with no functionality

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I am having a weird problem regarding the uiviewcontroller. When the view controller is called it comes up almost blank, with only the nav bar I put through storyboard. I have a class just for this controller which specifies how it should load and what to do once it does load etc. I have assigned this class to the view controller through storyboard. I added a button so when the button is pressed the view comes up. When the view comes up there is no functionality whatsoever. I tried creating other classes and assigned it to it but still no change. My classes are set to UIViewController. The code is the basic code from when you add a class:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface testViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

Anyone has any idea why this is happening? its been baffling me for hours.

[image: Here is the view controller in story board]

[image: Here is how it shows up during run time]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue a while ago. After some time investigating on the Web and the templates provided by XCode I found out that if you Implement the function - (void)loadView  to your ViewController the View won´t load or will just show black.

```
- (void)loadView
{
    // If you create your views manually, you MUST override this method and use it to create your views.
    // If you use Interface Builder to create your views, then you must NOT override this method.
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. What a pain a small function can become!